# Problem related to graphs within Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I was working on some problems in $n$-dimensional analysis the other day, and
I seem to have picked up on a problem that I can't quite sink my teeth into. Let
$M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a 2-dimensional surface of class $C^{\infty}$ and
let $(x_0,y_0,z_0) \in M.$ Consider the local chart $\phi : V \rightarrow
\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\phi(u_0,v_0) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ for some $(u_0,v_0)
\in V.$ I want to show that if $\det J_{\phi}(u_0,v_0)
\neq 0$ (i.e. the determinant
of the Jacobian of $\phi$ evaluated at the point $(u_0,v_0)$ is non-zero),
There exists $B((x_0,y_0,z_0),r) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$M \cap B((x_0,y_0,z_0),r)$ is the graph of the function $z = f(x,y)$ of class
$C^1.$

Note that the graph of a function is defined as
$$\text{Gr} f = \{(\mathbf{x},y) \in R \times \mathbb{R} | y = f(\mathbf{x})\}
,$$
where $R$ is an arbitrary set of certain dimensional vectors. I am having
difficulty figuring out if there is a useful theorem such that I can find
some properties of $B((x_0,y_0,z_0),r)$ to manipulate in order to induce
the proof onto this case. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: But $J_\phi$ is not square here, since $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, so $\det(J_\phi)$ isn't defined.